# Рандомный выбор + / -

Tags: c#

Как рандомно выбрать `+` и `-` для вычисления ?

```
int a = (10 / 2) тут 10
```

Answer (score 5):

Начните с вот такого:

```
if Random(2) = 0 then ..плюс.. else ..минус..
```

Продолжите вот таким:

```
a = (10 / 2) + 10 * (Random(2) * 2 - 1)
```

*язык не C#, но суть надеюсь понятна

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в том, как случайно выбирать оператор (сложение или вычитание), то подойдет следующий способ:

```
Random random = new Random();  
int a = 10 / 2; // первоначальное значение  
if (random.Next(0, 2) == 0) a += 10; // прибавить какое-то значение  
else a -= 10; // отнять какое-то значение
```

Или, если прибавляется/отнимается одно и то же выражение, можно похитрее:

```
Random random = new Random();  
int a = 10 / 2; // первоначальное значение  
a += (random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1) * 10;  
// выражение в половине случаев будет умножаться на -1, а только затем прибавляться
```

Answer (score 1):

**Способ 1.**

```
var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
Func<int> rndSign = () => (int)Math.Pow(-1, rnd.Next(1, 3));
```

**Способ 2.**

```
Func<int> rndSign = () => rnd.Next() == 1 ? 1 : -1;
var a = (10 / 2) + rndSign() * 10;
```